# Simulate in R the number of samples needed in order to achieve the true standard deviation

Tags: r, simulate, replicate

[image]

i want to recreate in R the figure above that simulates the number of samples needed in order to achieve the true standard deviation.
How can I do it in R ?

I suppose that the distribution is t-distribution or normal.
So I have to generate numbers from these distributions and each time to increase the size of the sample and plot it in order to recreate this plot as shown in the figure.
Any help ?

```
set.seed(123)

x <- list(v1=rnorm(1,0,12),v2=rnorm(10,0,11),
          v3=rnorm(20,0,10),v4=rnorm(30,0,9),
          v5=rnorm(40,0,8),v6=rnorm(50,0,7),
          v7=rnorm(60,0,6),v8=rnorm(70,0,5),
          v9=rnorm(80,0,4),v10=rnorm(90,0,3),
          v11=rnorm(100,0,2),v12=rnorm(110,0,2))

g = lapply(x,sd)
g
g1 = unlist(g)
plot(g1,type="l")
```

Comment: The plot you want to recreate does not look like it is gained from simulation but from a formula. If this is about recreating the plot you might be interested in Harding, B., Tremblay, C., & Cousineau, D. (2014) Standard errors: A review and evaluation of standard error estimators using Monte Carlo simulations , The Quantitative Methods for Psychology, 10(2), 107-123. doi: 10.20982/tqmp.10.2.p107 and there formulas 18 and 19 on page 112. cf https://www.tqmp.org/RegularArticles/vol10-2/p107/p107.pdf

Comment: yes exactly like this.But how this can be done in R?I have edited my question with a proposal in R.But it lacks of smoothness.So probably I am wrong.What I am trying to replicate is this : https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-03308-8_19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, start with a random uniform distribution of suitable size, and select which sample sizes you want to compute your standard error of the mean.

```
set.seed(123)

x <- runif(1e6, 0, 1)
sample_size <- 5:120
```

You can define a function to compute this `sigma_m`. Here you sample with replacement a sample of `n` from `x`, and take the standard deviation and divide by `sqrt(n)`.

```
calc_sigma_m <- function(n, x) {
  sd(sample(x, n, replace = TRUE))/sqrt(n)
}
```

A data frame can neatly store the sample sizes and `sigma_m` values for plotting:

```
df <- data.frame(sample_size, 
                 sigma_m = sapply(sample_size, calc_sigma_m, x))
```

Your initial plot will look like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(sample_size, sigma_m)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image: not smooth plot of sigma_m vs. sample size]

As expected, this is not smooth especially at smaller sample sizes.

If you want a smooth curve for demonstration, you repeat the sampling process and `sigma_m` calculation many times, and take the mean.

```
calc_sigma_m_mean <- function(n, x) {
  mean(replicate(1000, sd(sample(x, n, replace = TRUE))/sqrt(n)))
}        

df <- data.frame(sample_size, sigma_m = sapply(sample_size, calc_sigma_m_mean, x))
```

Then you will get a smoother curve:

```
ggplot(df, aes(sample_size, sigma_m)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image: smooth curve of sigma_m vs. sample size]